# A cancelled EVA for expedition 70?

Tags: iss, eva

I am wondering whether the December '23 EVA by Moghbeli and Mogensen (Expedition 70) is definitively canceled? If so, why? The mission ends now in  a few weeks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The EVA has not exactly been cancelled but apparently postponed to Expedition 71. According to a [January 25th, 2024 article](https://www.americaspace.com/2024/01/25/expedition-71-crew-discusses-six-month-iss-increment-crew-9-announcement-expected-next-week/) about Expedition 71 on AmericaSpace:

> Three Russian spacewalks are planned for early-to-midyear and Barratt teased about some “EVA content added to our mission” in the last “very few weeks”. NASA’s Rob Navias confirmed to AmericaSpace that a spacewalk previously slated to be performed by Expedition 70’s O’Hara and Mogensen in February has moved “until later in the year, due to the volume of work in February for the crewmembers on ISS”.

Michael Barratt is one of the four crew members of SpaceX Crew-8 which is scheduled to launch to ISS in late February/early March, initially as part of Expedition 70 and then switching to Expedition 71 in April with the departure of Soyuz MS-24. Loral O'Hara will be leaving on MS-24, Andreas Mogensen will be leaving ISS with the departure of Crew-7.